# What does mongoose.Schema return in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const modelSchema = new Schema({
    a: String,
    b: Date
});
```

I understand that the first line returns a mongoose. But what exactly does mongoose.Schema return in this code? Why do we need it to write the third line, "const modelSchema = new Schema(...)"?

Comment: Schema on the second line is the 'class' or object in Mongoose from which any new Schema instance is derived. You have to import the Schema object first, then in order to use it, you have instantiate a new instance for each model that you're needing a schema for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to.

It is just a shortcut for saving time writing all the time `mongoose.Schema` ... the above code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const modelSchema = new Schema({
    a: String,
    b: Date
});
```

Is the equivalent to:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const modelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    a: String,
    b: Date
});
```

So to answer your question the line which just gets a reference to the `mongoose.Schema` is nothing more than a `shortcut` to save yourself writing extra `mongoose.` every time :).

The main reason this is often used is since a lot of examples are given with more than one `schema` defined in a file/example. So to save time and not to repeat the same property path every time it is just referenced with a variable `Schema`.